# Is it possible for mods to earn all the Winterbash hats on a site they moderate?

Tags: discussion, moderation, winter-bash

There are several hats that are [seemingly impossible](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) for mods to obtain:

> Bouncer: Make 3 reviews in the close votes queue that ultimately get handled the way you recommended, and at least one other reviewer took the same action as you.

> Doorman: Make 3 reviews in the reopen votes queue that ultimately get handled the way you recommended, and if voting to Leave Closed at least one other reviewer took the same action as you.

> Chimney Sweep: Make 3 reviews in the suggested edits queue that ultimately get handled the way you recommended.

Does this mean a moderator could never collect all the hats on the website they moderate, since close/reopen/edit votes by moderators are binding and not subject to further review in the queue?

Comment: They also can't earn the Gimme Space hat ...

Comment: Why would these be impossible for a mod to earn? The "other reviewer" could have made their decision *first*, before the mod. Chimney Sweep is earned easily by moderators; just review 3 suggested edits. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray oh that's interesting! Care to add your answer?

Comment: Are hats retrained when accounts are merged?

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason why these three hats would be impossible for moderators to earn. Moderators can still review posts, and the fact that their decisions are binding just makes it *easier* for them to meet these thresholds.

I've already earned Chimney Sweep on the site I moderate just by reviewing 3 suggested edits. They were all handled in the way that I recommended. :-)

For Bouncer and Doorman, there is the additional requirement that "at least one other reviewer took the same action as you", but it doesn't require that that other review takes place *after* yours. The other reviewer could review the post first, followed by a moderator's review. If the moderator agreed with the previous reviewer, then the hat should be earned. (Haven't tested this yet. Need to find someone I agree with.)

Comment: Bouncer was one of the first hats I earned (after masks) on a site I mod. Can confirm it appeared just after I had been through the review queue, so almost certainly from closing after at least one vote to close from someone else.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problematic regular hats

---

#### Doorman

[image: Doorman]

> 3 successful reopen vote reviews

Solution: make your reopen vote the final vote

---

#### Chimney Sweep

[image: Chimney Sweep]

> 3 successful suggested edit reviews

Solution: make your edit review the final one

---

#### Carmen

[image: Carmen]

> Suggested edit approved

Solution: ?

---

#### Matryoshka

[image: Matryoshka]

> 10 successful close or reopen votes

Solution: cast your close/reopen votes as the last vote

---

#### Problematic secret hats

TBD based on what the criteria are

Comment: Carmen isn't really mod related... no high rep user with *full* editor privileges can get it.

Comment: (And by full that includes tag wiki edits, which are part of [Trusted User at 20k.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user))

Comment: @Catija Whom do we contact about removing our mod privileges so we can earn more hats? ;-)